# TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps Migration

Tags: sql, azure, tfs, azure-devops, migration

Currently i'm performing some dry-run to migrate from tfs 2015 to devop azure with no issues at all, altought i have a question that i cannot find the answer.

In my tfs 2015 i have 2 big collections and Microsoft provides the full tutorial to perform the migration of only 1 Collection. Can i migrate the 2 collections to 1 organization or i have to do 2 migrations 1 collection per organization?

If i need to do it seperatly, could the 2 organizations be connect to share build agents, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently a collection is somewhat equivalent to an account (or organization) in the service. This implies, that you have to create an organization per collection.

This also implies, that the two organizations are completely separated from each other and cannot share build agents. The only way to do this would be to install two agents on one build machine and register each agent at a different organization.